# How to create a conditional calculated column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

How to write a query to create a conditional and calculated field in SQL?

I am trying to merge two or more entities and the context of the entities are similar to the sample ones below. I am having an issue with regards to how to create the calculated field with the column *F* and *£* of *C-A*. I would greatly appreciate if I could get some help.

```
FlightTable                  AirportTable

AKEY  CODE  F    £           Code  City      Country
001   LHR   C    10          ATL   Atlanta   USA
002   BOS   C    15          BOS   Boston    USA
003   BOS   A    9            . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . .            . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
101   MAN   C    21          VIE   Schwechat Austria 
102   VIE   A    9           ZRH   Kloten    Switzerland
```

I am trying to get a result of a joined entity similar to:

```
Joined table

     CODE CITY    COUNTRY (£ Calculated Field)
001  BOS  Boston  USA      4
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use a case statement in the calculation.

```
     SELECT AIR.Code, AIR.City, AIR.Country, SUM(CASE WHEN flight.f = 'C' then £
                                                        when flight.f = 'A' then (-1) * £
                                                        else null
                                                        end) as "£ calculated"
     from AirportTable as "air" 
     join FlightTable as "flight" on "air".CODE = "flight".code -- could be AKEY = AKEY
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want two joins:

```
select a.*, (fc.£ - fa.£) as calculation
from airporttable a join
     flighttable fc
     on fc.code = a.code and fc.f = 'C' join
     flighttable fa
     on fa.code = a.code and fa.f = 'A';
```